# Why its necessary to use any string with dot point with self in class python(self.x=x)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning oop in python so i am having some problem to understand `sefl` keyword properly.

Suppose a program :

```
class ge:
   def __init__(self,a,b):
      self.p=a
      self.l=b
   def ff(self):
      aaa=self.p+self.l
      print(aaa)

hh=ge(1,2)
hh.ff()
```

I am confuse why its necessary to use any string with self with dot ? what it means ? Like:

self.a=a and we can change self.a to ay string like self.b , self.c what it means ?? why its necessary ?

My second question is :

what is difference between defining class with parameter and without parameter ?

```
class hello(object):
   def __init__(self,a,v):
      self.a=a
      self.v=v
   def p(self):
      f=self.a+self.v
      print(f)

he=hello(1,2)
he.p()
```

if i defined 
`class hello(object)` its working but 
if i defined class like:
`class hello():` its also working 
but if i defined like:
`class hello:`  its also working

what is the difference class `hello(object):`  , `class hello()`, `class hello:`

Comment: Please ask only one question in one post, your second question could be asked in a new post.

Comment: 1. `self` isn't a keyword, it's just an argument name that refers to the current instance of the class. You _could_ call it anything you like, but it's a convention to call it `self`. 2. In Python 3, there's no difference between `class hello(object):`, `class hello():`, or `class hello:`, but it's a good idea to use the 1st form if you want to write code that works correctly on Python 2 as well.

Comment: @PM2Ring    please never mark duplicate if you don't understand question properly.  i am not asking what is self , i know self make a attribute to global , i am asking something else. if you know what am asking then answer but don't mark unnecessary duplicate.

Comment: @khelwood please never mark duplicate if you don't understand question properly. i am not asking what is self , i know self make a attribute to global , i am asking something else. if you know what am asking then answer but don't mark unnecessary duplicate

Comment: "self make a attribute to global" I don't know exactly what you mean by that phrase, but it doesn't sound correct. There's a lot of good information in the target question linked at the top of this page, and in the questions linked in MMF's and Wonka's answers. Please study that information, and if you _still_ have a question on this topic that isn't covered by any of those answers, you can either add it to the bottom of this question and it may be re-opened, or you can ask a fresh question.

Comment: @kennytm i wanted quick answer and new user can ask only one question in 90 minute.

Comment: @PM2Ring i didn't find what i was asking. If you know the answer please answer or let me ask question.
i am not asking what is "self" and how its use. I am asking can we attach any string with self and how this string works ?

Comment: I'm still not totally clear on what your actual question is. In your `ge.__init__` method, the statement `self.p=a` creates an attribute of the current instance of the `ge` object. That attribute is named 'p' and the assignment binds the `self.p` name to the object that was passed to `ge.__init__` in the `a` parameter. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question** : Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

**Second question** : There is no difference between the different notations. When you use the parenthesis it means that your class *inherits* from the class between parenthesis.

In python 3, by default every class inherits from the class `object`. So `hello(object):` , `class hello():`, `class hello:` are totally equivalent.
In python 2 however, you must explicit the inheritance.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) are more details on how to create classes in python.

Comment: "by default every class inherits from the class object" That's true in Python 3, but not in Python 2, which is why you need to explicitly inherit from `object` if you want a [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (and you probably do).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the precision ! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

self is used to reference the instance of the class, is like this in Java

Duplicated:
[When do you use 'self' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721920/when-do-you-use-self-in-python)

Comment: Not the *class*, but the *instance*!