# What exactly self and -> int mean in this python snippet def line1(self, arr: List[int], a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:

Tags: python-3.x

For the pythons snippet below,

```
def line1(self, arr: List[int], a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
```

what does  -> int mean? what is the purpose of b:int then? also what does self mean?

Comment: Refer [Type Hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions) and [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/4518341)

Comment: Two of the things you ask are related to type hints, but if you're not familiar with self you should check out a structured tutorial https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: for self see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7721920/217324

Answer (score 0):

Please at least try to use Google. Those are very simple questions.

But anyway:

self - means that a function belongs to a class and with self all the class attributes are passed to function so it could access them

-> - is a relatively new feature in python, it helps with a type annotation, it defines what function will return. In this case, the function is expected to return an integer value.

: - has the same purposes as the "arrow" from above it means that function expects to receive an integer value for a, b and c

You have got yourself some useful links in comments, please go over them.