# Python Unit Test Case error: takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, inorder

Having issues in running a test case for python Binary Search Tree Traversal. It gives an error as:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_case_1 (__main__.TestProgram)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BST_traversal.py", line 31, in test_case_1
    self.assertEqual(root.inOrderTraversal(root,[]),inOrder)
TypeError: inOrderTraversal() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The code for BST is:

```
import unittest

class BST:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def inOrderTraversal(self,array):
        if self is not None:
            inOrderTraversal(self.left,array)
            array.append(self.value)
            inOrderTraversal(self.right,array)
        return array

class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        root = BST(10)
        
        root.left = BST(5)
        root.left.left = BST(2)
        root.left.left.left = BST(1)
        root.left.right = BST(5)
        root.right = BST(15)
        root.right.right = BST(22)

        inOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 22]
        preOrder = [10, 5, 2, 1, 5, 15, 22]
        postOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 22, 15, 10]

        self.assertEqual(root.inOrderTraversal(root,[]),inOrder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Even after making a seperate class for BST does not help me out too much.

Comment: Python's [`self` argument is implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721920/when-do-you-use-self-in-python).  You will need to make major adjustments to your implementation (either create separate standalone functions, or modify the `inOrderTraversal` to take in additional argument(s)).

Answer (score 2):

self is a hidden param, you not need to given

```
import unittest


class BST:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def inOrderTraversal(self, data, array):
        if data is not None:
            data.inOrderTraversal(data.left, array)
            array.append(data.value)
            data.inOrderTraversal(data.right, array)
        return array


class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        root = BST(10)

        root.left = BST(5)
        root.left.left = BST(2)
        root.left.left.left = BST(1)
        root.left.right = BST(5)
        root.right = BST(15)
        root.right.right = BST(22)

        inOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 22]
        preOrder = [10, 5, 2, 1, 5, 15, 22]
        postOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 22, 15, 10]
        arr = root.inOrderTraversal(root, [])
        print(arr)
        self.assertEqual(arr, inOrder)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

```
.
[1, 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 22]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import unittest

class BST:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def inOrderTraversal(self,array):
        if self and self.left:
            self.left.inOrderTraversal(array)
        if self:
            array.append(self.value)
        if self and self.right:
            self.right.inOrderTraversal(array)
        return array

class TestProgram(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        root = BST(10)

        root.left = BST(5)
        root.left.left = BST(2)
        root.left.left.left = BST(1)
        root.left.right = BST(5)
        root.right = BST(15)
        root.right.right = BST(22)

        inOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 22]
        preOrder = [10, 5, 2, 1, 5, 15, 22]
        postOrder = [1, 2, 5, 5, 22, 15, 10]

        self.assertEqual(root.inOrderTraversal([]),inOrder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

That should run. You are getting very close, just need to understand how the `self` parameter works. Also `is not None` is redundant, FYI.